# Web design and developement colaboration using photoshop

Tags: css, user-interface, web, photoshop, zeplin

I'm a web developer. For collaboration me and designers used Zeplin (https://zeplin.io/), which gives me a lot information (page components sizes, colors, css settings like font, borders, even something like border-radius and stuff I think).

But now on another project I've been given just a PSD (Photoshop) file. How can I extract all this information (which Zeplin gives me) from this PSD file?

P.S. I don't have a Photoshop license.

Comment: Why downvote and close, a comment would be helpful?

Comment: I would assume that you were down voted because your question has nothing to do with programming and therefore is not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm a programmer and am doing web programming currently. This question is required for me to finish my web programming task. I need to make css (jss) as per design given in photoshop file. So it has to do with css and web programming, so it has to do with programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this service: http://avocode.com

It displays all needed information and has a free 14-days license

Comment: Excellent tool. Just what I needed!

Comment: This answered perfectly. The suggestion is to use avocode service, and provides a link to the service. This is the essence of the answer.